# Can I explicitly specify template arguments for an operator?

Tags: c++

I have the class Foo:

```
class Foo {
    template <typename T>
    T* operator () (void) {
        return (T*) something;
    }
}
```

T can't be deduced, but what I want is to be able to say something like

```
Foo foo;    
type_t bar = foo <type_t> ();
```

But this is a syntax error.

Is there a way to do this?
(or perhaps some better way to pass in a type without providing an instance of the type?)

Comment: You're returning `T *`, so your return has to be `type_t *`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it using the operator name syntax:

```
type_t *bar = foo.operator() <type_t> ();
```

That's of course ugly. There are two solutions:

1. Change the operator so that it takes a parameter and thus the type is deducible.
2. Change it from an operator to a named function. It doesn't seem like a typical use for `operator()` anyway.

Comment: Thanks,  I was googling in frustration for awhile to figure out what to call it. Title updated.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example which compiles and runs:

```
struct Foo {
    template <typename T>
    T* operator () () {
        return (T*) 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    double* bar = Foo().operator()<double>();
}
```

But that's *really* ugly. It is a clear case of operator-overloading abuse. Consider using an ordinary function name. Operator overloading should make code faster to read, not the opposite.